# Transfer from Intercity train to Warsaw Chopin

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, poland, warsaw

I'll be travelling on the train (PKP Intercity) from Bydgoszcz to Warsaw Central to catch a mid-afternoon flight from Warsaw Chopin airport (LOT Airlines to Heathrow). Is a two-hour window between the train's scheduled arrival time and the flight's departure time likely to be sufficient, given that I need to check a bag? Is there a high risk that the train will be delayed? I'm happy to go by the quickest method (which I imagine would be a taxi?) even if it costs more.

Comment: Taxi might be sligthly quickest than the suggested train. At the same time it might happen it's slower. The train connection is reliable and predictable (you check the time table). The downside is that you need to buy a separate ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the train to the airport. You would have to change trains at Warsaw Zachodnia, from where a suburban train takes you to the airport in 15 minutes. You can probably do this all on one ticket even.

Comment: The PKP Intercity ticket won't be valid for the Chopin airport service as it's operated by a different entity.

Comment: The PKP website however does suggest you can buy the IC and airport train ticket together.

Comment: oh I didn't see that. Mine "only" offers a Bydgoszcz -> Łódź -> Chopin airport trip.

Comment: Well, the PKP site is not that easy to navigate. So some local input would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I've already bought the ticket to Warsaw Central; will I be allowed to change at Warsaw Zachodnia if I buy a ticket from there to the airport?

Comment: It is highly probable that your train also stops in Warsaw Zachodnia. And there is nothing stopping you from getting of there. (Getting of an an earlier stop is perfectly legal). Then get a ticket for the airport there and go. You can get to the airport from Central as well, but there are more trains from Zachodnia.

Comment: Commenting after having made the journey: The PKP train was delayed by about five minutes. I disembarked and changed at Zachodnia as Krist suggested, which I found to be less confusing than Central and there were announcements in English. Train did indeed take 15 minutes, or thereabouts. I had about an hour and 40 minutes between getting to the airport and flight departure.